# WAR file placed in another tomcat server is deployed on running startup.bat for another tomcat server

Tags: tomcat

I have two tomcat servers, one runs on port P1 and another on P2. Now the bizarre thing that is happening is that when I run the startup.bat for server2 the war file for server1 is deployed and I can run the app which is present in the webapps folder of server1. And the WAR present in the server2 is never deployed. Further when I run the startup.bat for server1 and then I run the shutdown.bat for server2 the server1 process shuts down and vice versa is also true. Somehow the server2 has become connected to the server1. I have no idea how something like this can be possible. Any help appreciated.

On running the startup.bat for server2 I get the following logs

```
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.035 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version [1.1.27] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.067 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version [1.1.27] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server built:          Jun 30 2020 21:49:10 UTC
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Server version number: 8.5.57.0
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Name:               Windows 10
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log OS Version:            10.0
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Architecture:          amd64
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_202
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Version:           1.8.0_202-b08
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_BASE:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.config.file=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\conf\logging.properties
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] 
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dignore.endorsed.dirs=
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener.log Command line argument: -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\temp
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.113 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version [1.1.27] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.254 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener.init An incompatible version [1.1.27] of the Apache Tomcat Native library is installed, while Tomcat requires version [1.2.14]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.254 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.348 INFO [main] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool.getSharedSelector Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.363 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Initialization processed in 611 ms
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.395 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.57
19-Apr-2021 05:10:09.425 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57\webapps\Server1.war]
19-Apr-2021 05:10:13.567 INFO [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
```

The path for the Server2 tomcat is this

```
C:\tomcat2\apache-tomcat-7.0.37
```

And the path for Server1 is this

```
C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57
```

That is the two tomcat servers are of diff version.

Also when I start server1 and then I try to start server2 I get the following error. Same error is received when server2 is started first and then server1 is tried to start

```
19-Apr-2021 03:52:05.348 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-8080]]
        org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1077)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:552)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:848)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:136)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:639)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:662)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:302)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:472)
        Caused by: java.net.BindException: Address already in use: bind
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind0(Native Method)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.Net.bind(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
                at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketAdaptor.bind(Unknown Source)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.bind(NioEndpoint.java:221)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:1118)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractJsseEndpoint.init(AbstractJsseEndpoint.java:222)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:587)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Protocol.init(AbstractHttp11Protocol.java:74)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:1075)
```

Comment: Please add some details to your question: run `startup.bat` from `cmd` and copy/paste the `Using ...: ...` lines to your question. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67156208/edit) your question instead of posting them as comments.

Comment: Please let me know if any other info is required @PiotrP.Karwasz

Comment: As you can see both `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` for server2 are set to `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57`. Check if these values are not set globally in your Windows system (cf. [this question](https://superuser.com/q/341192/1066525)). If they are, remove them so that `startup.bat` can apply its heuristic to set them properly per server.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. Please post this as answer, so that I can accept it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your log shows that both the `CATALINA_HOME` and `CATALINA_BASE` are set to `C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.57`. Check if those environment variables are not set globally in your Windows system and remove them.

The `*.bat` scripts in your Tomcat installation use some heuristic (based on the location of the `*.bat` file) to set those variables. However this only happens if they are **unset**.